# Approximation error when using sqrt and floor

Tags: c++, numerical, approximation

I have to do an enumeration of solutions of an equation and I know that  `y < x *( sqrt(n) - 1 )`, where *x*, *y* and *n* are integers.

My naive approach would be to look for *y* less or equal than `floor( x * ( sqrt( (float)n ) - 1 ) )`.

---

- Should I be worried about approximation error?
- For example, if my expression is a little be greater than an integer *m*, should I be worried to get *m-1* at the end?
- How could I detect such errors?

Comment: One improvement is to take the multiplication outside the `floor` call.

Comment: Do you need a numeric upper bound on `y`, or just a stopping condition for a loop?  For example, if x is positive, that condition is equivalent to: `((x+y) < 0) || ((x+y)*(x+y) < n*x*x)` and when x is negative, it simplifies to `(x+y)*(x+y) > n*x*x`

Comment: I think you need the multiplication inside the `floor` rather than outside: e.g. with x=10, n=15: `floor(x*sqrt((float)n)-x)` gives 28 while `x*floor(sqrt((float)n)-1)` gives 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely be worried about approximation error, but how worried depends upon the ranges of values for *x* and *n* you are concerned about.

Calculations in IEEE 4-byte floating point representations are going to have errors roughly on the order of one part in 2^23 to 2^24; for an 8-byte representation (i.e, a `double`), it will be roughly one part in 2^52 to 2^53. You could expect then that you would need to use `double`s rather than `float`s to get an accurate result for 32-bit integers *x* and *n*, and that even a `double` would be insufficient for 64-bit integers.

As an example, consider the code:

```
template <typename F,typename V>
F approxub(V x,V n) {
    return std::floor(x*std::sqrt(F(n))-x);
}

uint64_t n=1000000002000000000ull; // (10^9 + 1)^2 - 1
uint64_t x=3;
uint64_t y=approxub<double>(x,n);
```

This gives a value of *y*=3000000000, but the correct value is 2999999999.

It's even worse when *x* is large and *n* is small: large 64-bit integers are not exactly representable in IEEE `double`s:

```
uint64_t n=9;
uint64_t x=5000000000000001111; // 5e18 + 1111
uint64_t y=approxlb<double>(x,n);
```

The correct value for y (putting to one side the issue of when *n* is a perfect square — the true upper bound will be one less in this case) is 2 *x* = 10000000000000002222, i.e. 1e19 + 2222. The computed *y* is, however, 10000000000000004096.

### Avoiding floating point approximations

Suppose you had a function `isqrt` which exactly computed the integer part of the square-root of an integer. Then you could say

```
y = isqrt(x*x*n) - x
```

and provided that the product `x*x*n` fit inside your integer type, you would have an exact upper bound (or one more than the upper bound if *n* is a perfect square.) There's more than one way to write an `isqrt` function; this is an example implementation based on the [material at code codex](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_an_integer_square_root):

```
template <typename V>
V isqrt(V v) {
    if (v<0) return 0;

    typedef typename std::make_unsigned<V>::type U;
    U u=v,r=0;

    constexpr int ubits=std::numeric_limits<U>::digits;
    U place=U(1)<<(2*((ubits-1)/2));

    while (place>u) place/=4;
    while (place) {
        if (u>=r+place) {
            u-=r+place;
            r+=2*place;
        }
        r/=2;
        place/=4;
    }
    return (V)r;
}
```

What if *x* is too large for this? For example, if our largest integral type has 64 bits, and *x* is larger than 2^32. The most straightforward solution would be to do a binary search, taking as bounds *x r - x* and *x r*, where *r* = [√*n*] is the integer square root.

Comment: I've a feeling that "enumeration of solutions" rules out such large ranges.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use the isqrt function but the information about the representations of decimal numbers is really imteresting.